# MySQL crashes frequently

Tags: mysql

I am facing frequent MySQL crash problem. Not sure how to fix the problem. Attaching the mysql error log. How can I improve the performance? Suggest me a solution.

#### Server Config

Digitalocean SSD server
1GB RAM
CentOS 6.5
64-bit kernel
Apache

2 wordpress website hosted
Avg. Daily traffic 2000

#### MySQL configuration

```
max_connections=50  
wait_timeout=30  
query_cache_size=15M  
tmp_table_size=46M
max_heap_table_size=46M
thread_cache_size=4
innodb_buffer_pool_size=500M
table_cache=70

slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysqld/slow-query.log
```

#### Error Log

```
140530 10:56:03 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
140530 10:56:03 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
140530 10:56:03  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 500.0M
140530 10:56:03  InnoDB: Error: cannot allocate 524304384 bytes of
InnoDB: memory with malloc! Total allocated memory
InnoDB: by InnoDB 7994352 bytes. Operating system errno: 12
InnoDB: Check if you should increase the swap file or
InnoDB: ulimits of your operating system.
InnoDB: On FreeBSD check you have compiled the OS with
InnoDB: a big enough maximum process size.
InnoDB: Note that in most 32-bit computers the process
InnoDB: memory space is limited to 2 GB or 4 GB.
InnoDB: We keep retrying the allocation for 60 seconds...
140530 10:57:03InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate the memory for the buffer pool
140530 10:57:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140530 10:57:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140530 10:57:03 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: InnoDB
140530 10:57:03 [ERROR] Aborting

140530 10:57:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140530 10:57:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140530 10:57:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140530 10:57:08  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 500.0M
140530 10:57:08  InnoDB: Error: cannot allocate 524304384 bytes of
InnoDB: memory with malloc! Total allocated memory
InnoDB: by InnoDB 7994352 bytes. Operating system errno: 12
InnoDB: Check if you should increase the swap file or
InnoDB: ulimits of your operating system.
InnoDB: On FreeBSD check you have compiled the OS with
InnoDB: a big enough maximum process size.
InnoDB: Note that in most 32-bit computers the process
InnoDB: memory space is limited to 2 GB or 4 GB.
InnoDB: We keep retrying the allocation for 60 seconds...
140530 10:58:09InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate the memory for the buffer pool
140530 10:58:09 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140530 10:58:09 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140530 10:58:09 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: InnoDB
140530 10:58:09 [ERROR] Aborting

140530 10:58:09 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140530 10:58:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140530 10:58:40 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140530 10:58:40  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 500.0M
140530 10:58:40  InnoDB: Error: cannot allocate 524304384 bytes of
InnoDB: memory with malloc! Total allocated memory
InnoDB: by InnoDB 7994352 bytes. Operating system errno: 12
InnoDB: Check if you should increase the swap file or
InnoDB: ulimits of your operating system.
InnoDB: On FreeBSD check you have compiled the OS with
InnoDB: a big enough maximum process size.
InnoDB: Note that in most 32-bit computers the process
InnoDB: memory space is limited to 2 GB or 4 GB.
InnoDB: We keep retrying the allocation for 60 seconds...
140530 10:59:40InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate the memory for the buffer pool
140530 10:59:40 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140530 10:59:40 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140530 10:59:40 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: InnoDB
140530 10:59:40 [ERROR] Aborting

140530 10:59:40 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140530 10:59:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140530 10:59:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140530 10:59:53  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 500.0M
140530 10:59:53  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 0 2392450950
140530 10:59:53  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 2392452317
140530 10:59:53  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
140530 10:59:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 2392452317
140530 10:59:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140530 10:59:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Comment: It quite clearly states it cannot allocate memory.

Comment: Fixing crashing is not the same as improving performance.

Comment: 1GB RAM -> 2GB? 4GB? 8? Even 16? Running 1GB of RAM on a 64 bit kernel on an SSD server strikes me as a false economy - instead of fast disks, you need more RAM. Can't tell real origin of problem - but how much is a 16GB of RAM these days? ~ $150

Comment: I didn't realise DigitalOcean was a cloud provider and not a server OEM. Talk to them about the issue - maybe consider an upgrade - to 2GB for $10/month?